# Install beautifulsoup under python3 with python2 as default Python version

Tags: python-3.x, path, beautifulsoup, installation

I used python2 as the default python path on my mac. and it already had beautifulsoup installed. 
I installed python3 recently and would like to install beautifulsoup under python3. I tried to copy the bs4 folder under python3 folder, but I cannot even find the python3 folder.

I used

```
import sys 

print (sys.path)
```

and it returned '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip'.but there is no version 3.5 under that frame.

Can anyone please tell me how can I install beautifulsoup under python3?
since my default path is to python2, everytime I run pip install, it installed the bs under python2..

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pip3` executable:

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

You might need to *run it with `sudo`.*

Comment: it works! thank you so much! I really appreciate your help!